# Simple_form_for nested form whitelisting attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, simple-form

I'm trying to create a form that automatically saves awards to a ceremony when that ceremony is created. I have done my best to follow the guides, https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models, and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html, however I keep getting the error

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
```

My code is as follows:

ceremony.rb

```
class Ceremony < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :awards
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :awards, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: lambda { |attributes| attributes['kind'].blank?
end
```

award.rb

```
class Award < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ceremony
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for ceremony do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title %>
  <% 3.times do Award.new %>
    <%= field_set_tag 'Award' do %>
      <%= f.simple_fields_for 'awards_attributes[]', award do |g| %>
        <%= g.input :title %>
        <%= g.input :description %>
        <%= g.input :category_id, as: :select, collection: Category.all %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And finally ceremonies_controller.rb

```
class CeremoniesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    ceremony = Ceremony.new(ceremony_params)
    handle_create(ceremony)
  end

  def new
    ceremony = Ceremony.new
  end

  private

  def handle_create

def handle_create(ceremony)
  if ceremony.save
    create_participant_and_awards(ceremony)
    redirect_to ceremony,
                notice: 'Ceremony successfully created'
  else
    render :new, error: 'There was an error adding the ceremony'
  end
end

def ceremony_params
  params.require(:ceremony).permit(:title, awards_attributes: [:title, :description, :category_id, :ceremony_id])
end
```

When I fill out the form and click on submit, it does not create any associated awards. They are passed in the paramaters, which are as follows:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"2MdHYpZW4POOx2STvPP8sDh6lAtisy2dJDEuC1FaKMpOHUmwsQnk6GztnrrS8E2FC5ajvuhGCdZr56QgQMQAag==", "ceremony"=>{"title"=>"Test 1", "organisation"=>"test 1", "description"=>"", "closing_time(1i)"=>"2017", "closing_time(2i)"=>"4", "closing_time(3i)"=>"27", "closing_time(4i)"=>"17", "closing_time(5i)"=>"35", "organiser_id"=>"1", "awards_attributes"=>[{"title"=>"test2", "description"=>"test 2", "category_id"=>"1"}, {"title"=>"test 3", "description"=>"test 3", "category_id"=>"3"}, {"title"=>"test 4", "description"=>"test 4", "category_id"=>"2"}]}, "commit"=>"Create Ceremony"}
```

I know I need to white list the parameters, but as far as I can see I have, following the guide. I don't get how else I can whitelist what I need. Any help is GREATLY appreciated

Comment: check ceremony.errors before you save it, or just do ceremony.save! . it will throw an exception with the validation error

Comment: the ceremony saves without an issue, it just doesn't create the associated awards

Comment: also, I usually also write has_many :awards in Ceremony
can you try that and check?

Comment: Sorry was in there but I forgot to copy - have added it now